# Get updated XSRF token and Cookie after login: Angular 4

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular4-httpclient, x-xsrf-token

I have an app where user logs in and send some requests to nodeJs backend. In my app first I send a dummy request then I get a _csrf and XSRF-token I set these as headers and send login details. In login response I get a new XSRF-token in cookie. I need to add that to the header of post request that I do after login.

Here is my **auth.service.ts**

```js
export class AuthService {

  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('users/register', user, { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('users/authenticate', user, { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('users/profile', { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }

  logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

my component where I send post request after login

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  authToken: any;

  public data: any[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @ViewChild('f') tslForm: NgForm;
  onTslSubmit(f) {
    var tslDetails = {
      investingAmount: f.value.investingAmount, tradeStartAmount: f.value.tradeStartAmou$

    this.add(tslDetails).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data, "response of send request");
      }, error => {
        console.log(error, "error");
      });
      this.tslForm.reset();
    }

    add(data: any){
      console.log(data, "before submit data");

      const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
      this.authToken = token;
      console.log("authToken: " + this.authToken);
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': this.authToken,
        })
      }

      return this.http.post("http://0.0.0.0:3000/dummyurl", data, httpOptions).map((res: Response) => $
     }

  }
```

I need to send a post request with headers having updated XSRF token and cookie as this post request from postman.

[image]

Comment: Your code in the second part is not proper typescript. Correct this please.